# Workaround for cron time limitations

Tags: php, linux, cron

So basically I'm using a cron job to execute a php script that requires quite a bit of time to run (Pulling down updated xml from ftp, unzipping, mysql manipulation, api access, etc.). The issue is that we are running on a server that limits the time a cron job can be run to 15 minutes.

My question is this: what methods can be used to work around this limitation? Breaking the script up into pieces would still causes pieces to run over the 15 minute time limit, so that's out. Are there any ways to redirect to another php script after executing for a certain amount of time? Or could a bash script be used in some way to restart the script before the 15 minute time limit is reached?

Thanks!

Comment: you would probably break your hosts terms, trying to circumvent any restrictions they put in to place, i would look in to getting a dedicated box, or moving host.

Comment: Yup, get a virtual server, then you can run your cron every minute. I'm starting some work with gearman: http://gearman.org/. It might help with processing your jobs.

Comment: What would be the best way to do it if not through a cron?

Comment: Is it cron that has the 15-minute time limit, or is it that any process you run has a 15 minute time limit?  Also, be sure to upvote and/or accept an answer that you find helpful here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first advice would be to find a new host, but it sounds like thats not an option for you right now.

You could keep track of your runtime and **save your state** in a DB or flat file just before you hit the 15 minute time limit.  The next go-round in cron would then look at the DB or file and know where to pick up where you left off.

This depends on what your script is doing of course.  If you're just performing the same task on X number of records, it sounds like you may be able to implement something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda depends on how they have the limit implemented.  You could perhaps use `exec()` and launch another script at some point to break up the process.

You can't really 'restart' a script.  If you could, it'd just start from scratch anyways.

I don't get why you cant break it up?  You get 15 minutes of usage for scripts launched from cron per day or what?  Sounds like you need a different host provider, that limit seems very lame. And 15 minutes, what kind of huge files are you dealing with.  Maybe you should work on getting it to run in less than 15 minutes.

**EDIT**

I was thinking, since the limit sounds like it is just on scripts run from cron, why don't you have the actual cron on another system, and just use wget to call the script on the remote server.

Comment: The server is on rackspace cloud hosting, and I agree on the limitation being ridiculous! However, I'm not in a position to move hosting at the moment. The script is doing API calls that take quite a while, especially executing on 50,000 records. Could it be possible to send a header inside the php script with a $_GET variable to give a place marker?

Comment: Ya you could call up a step 2 after it had gone through a certain amount of the script, but I don't see how that will help you, it won't be any different than if you had broken it up and ran it as different jobs to begin with... im editing my answer to give what could be another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try having the cron job background the script. Something like

```
 0 0 * * * php /path/to/file.php &
```

I have never tried this tactic as I've never had cron jobs that run that long, but it will disassociate the script from cron